# Siddhi: state persistence and realtime queryable state?

Tags: wso2, siddhi

**My Scenario is like this.**

I want to see/query what is the current aggregation value(s) of a particular query of the active processing window.

I have seen this in [Apache Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/queryable_state.html).

***For e.g:***

Say I have a query to count total number of failures, windowing to every 12 hours. And I want to ask (from another application) what is the *current count* for *active aggregating window*. Note that active window is still processing.

Reason is that my application need to give a feedback to the user regarding its current total failure count. So he/she can act based on that. Waiting until the window is processed and get the count then, is not the desired behavior in the perspective of user.

Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [rolling time window](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#time-window). Rolling time window will give you the rolling aggregation(sum, count, etc) for a given time range. So for every incoming event you will get an output event with the count. You can use that to give feedback. There are two catches of this approach. One is it is a rolling count not a batch count. Other one is process is triggered with events to count stream. If you want to trigger the feedback depending on another requirement(Ex: user initiated, every hour etc) this approach will not work. For that you need to use below approach.

Use a [time batch window](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/api/latest/#timeBatch-window) and then join it with another stream which will get triggered depending on the business requirement. Below is a sample and here are the [testcases](https://github.com/tishan89/siddhi/blob/f3e40ec268c5c79e403aa3070beb31e8b90a7da4/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/query/join/OuterJoinTestCase.java#L34) for your reference.

```
from countStream#window.timeBatch(12 hrs) right outer join 
feedbackTriggerStream#window.length(1)
select count() as totalFailures
insert into FeedbackStream;
```

Another option is to use the [query](https://wso2.github.io/siddhi/documentation/siddhi-4.0/#tablewindow-select) feature. This approach is suitable if you are using Siddhi as a library and you have access to SiddhiAppRuntime. Below is a code sample for that. Lets assume below is your window query to calculate count.

```
define countWindow(userid string, reason string) timeBatch(12 hrs);

From countStream
Select *
Insert into countWindow;
```

Then you can use queries as below to access window data.

```
Event[] events = siddhiAppRuntime.query(
"from countWindow " +
"select count() as totalCount ");
```

events will contain the one event with count. Here is a reference to [testcases](https://github.com/tishan89/siddhi/blob/f3e40ec268c5c79e403aa3070beb31e8b90a7da4/modules/siddhi-core/src/test/java/org/wso2/siddhi/core/store/StoreQueryWindowTestCase.java#L32).